# MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR exception in IBM MQ and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, message-queue, ibm-mq

I am using MQ.NET classes, however when i specify the correct queue manager, i still get this below error.

Exception:

CompCode: 2, Reason: 2058
MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR
 Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}

Message: "MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR"
Source: "amqmdnet"

```
MQQueueManager mqQMgr=null; 
//MYMGRTEST is my queue manager
mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager("MYMGRTEST"); -> This piece of line throws above exception.
```

What are the possible reasons this can happen(network permission/admin rights/?) ?  Any measures to correct this?

Also i see this information in the error log under errors folders of websphere.

> AMQ9518: File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\AMQCLCHL.TAB'
>   not found.

EXPLANATION:
The program requires that the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere
MQ\AMQCLCHL.TAB' is present and available.

ACTION:
This may be caused by invalid values for the optional environment variables
MQCHLLIB, MQCHLTAB or MQDATA. If these variables are valid or not set then
record the name of the file and tell the systems administrator who must ensure
that file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\AMQCLCHL.TAB' is available
to the program.

Not sure what that error is about, as i have installed MQ client in my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you are setting the MQEnvironment:

```
MQEnvironment.channel
MQEnvironment.port
MQEnvironment.hostname
```

You need to set correct value in them. Like:

```
MQEnvironment.hostname="localhost", 
MQEnvironment.port=1414
MQEnvironment.channel="SYSTEM.DEF.CHANNEL"
```

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks, also setting MQSERVER data in environment variable and accessing back in the code is the best way to pass dynamic valies for host and channel names. (Refer -> nmqsput.cs (C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base) for sample code for this.