# Unable to connect at IBM WebSphere MQ 8.xx

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect to an IBM WebSphere MQ 8.x, but what should be simple as it's with RabbitMQ seems so difficult on IBM world.

I've created a Console Application (.NET Framework), referenced the amqmdnet.dll 8.0.0.10)

and here's my snippet

```
    var connectionName = "X.X.X.X(4418)";

    Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
    properties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, connectionName);
    properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY,"TEST_XXX_RECEIVER");

    var mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager("DEFAULT.XXXMQCOL1",properties );
    mqQMgr.Connect();
```

What I got when trying to connect is IBM.WMQ.MQException: 'MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR'

For that concern the Queue name I've put the name I found on the node

[image]

The Channel property is a channel I've defined in the queue node of websphere

I've tried to telnet on ip:port and it connects

Any suggestion?

## UPDATE #1

[image]

Even if I do "Start" from context menu, it remains inactive, can this lead to the constructor's hang?

## UPDATE #2

I've managed it. I was going wrong on two steps

1. I have the LISTENER.TCP stopped under the listeners
2. I was pointing at 4418 which is the Queue Manager port and I had to point at 1414 (Listener.TCP port)

Now I'm able to connect, admin you can close it

Comment: You have empty `hashTable` variable and the `properties` variable. And now lets see which one you passing to `MQQueueManager`...

Comment: I've removed the hashTable and only used the properties is used. but it hangs on the MQQueueManager

Comment: I edited it... I've tried all morning long but with no succes... so it was a misprint

Comment: Check `%MQ_FILE_PATH%\errors\AMQERR01.LOG` for errors and update question with what is found.

Comment: In the past I worked much more to get it to work and it is hard to tell what you are doing wrong. Mostly the problems where related with websphere configuration. Just google all errors you get and try. Here is [MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672582/mqrc-q-mgr-name-error-exception-in-ibm-mq-and-net) and here is [an example how to connect](https://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2007/04/13/Connecting-to-MQSeries-with-.NET.aspx) (read notes about mqm user if you get authorization errors)

Comment: I've just looked at the first link you've posted @Reniuz, I also think the problem is somehwere on the websphere side...See the #UPDATE1 , I've got a Overall sender state "Inactive", can this be the cause?

Comment: See @MarkTaylor's answer, but in summary you stated "`The Channel property is a channel I've defined in the queue node of websphere`", in the screen shot the channel you highlight shows Channel type `Sender` which is a friendlier name for the MQ channel type `SDR`, client apps connect to `SVRCONN` channels not `SDR` channels.

Comment: Your Update #2 makes no sense, based on the screenshot you provided in Update #1 you had the incorrect channel type defined.  MQ has three basic types of listeners, the normal MQ listener, the AMQP listener and the MQTT listener.  What exactly do you mean by "I was pointing at 4418 which is the Queue Manager port and I had to point at 1414 (Listener.TCP port)".  In that context what was port 4418?  If Mark Taylor's answer helped you you should accept it and vote it up, you have plenty of rep to do that.

Comment: This is a site were people just like you answer other peoples questions, adding a comment "admin you can close it" would likely not be read by anyone that actually works for StackExchange.   If you feel your question should be closed as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced" you can do this yourself, but I think it is clear that you were pointing to a channel that was the wrong type (Sender) and part of fixing your problem must have involved you pointing to a channel of the proper type (SVRCONN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using sender and/or receiver channels. Use SVRCONN for clients